# Delphi Log user session state events

Tags: delphi, windows-services

How i can implement windows service that log all users session state events ?

In the applications i used `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE` message to receive all the events changes in session state.

How i can implement the same in windows service ?

Comment: Please read the docs: *"To receive session change notifications from a service, use the HandlerEx function."*

Comment: You **cannot** use Delphi's stock `TService` framework for this, it *STILL DOES NOT* use [`HandlerEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683241.aspx) (after all these years!), only [`Handler()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683240.aspx), which does not support `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE`.  Use a 3rd party service framework that *DOES* use `HandlerEx()` (like [SvCom](http://www.aldyn-software.com/svcom.html)), or else [write your own service code from scratch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685967.aspx).

Comment: Otherwise, you would have to continuously poll the current user sessions using [`WTSEnumerateSessions()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383833.aspx) looking for changes.  Much less efficient than handling `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` events.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you for the guidance.